# How to show that $a+b> \sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}, \qquad a, b >0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

How do you show that 
$$a+b> \sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}, \qquad a, b >0$$

I could write $\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-3ab}$, but this seems to lead nowhere.

Comment: Try squaring both sides.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath, squaring both sides actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a+b> \sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab} \iff (a+b)^2>\left (\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}\right )^2$$  $$ \iff\quad a^2+2ab+b^2>a^2+b^2-ab$$ $$\iff\quad 3ab>0 \quad \iff\quad ab>0$$ which is correct because of the hypothesis $a,b >0$.

Comment: Why do you suggest(in edit) to use $\Rightarrow \quad$ instead of $\iff$? At what step can't I go backwards?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2ab > -ab \Rightarrow a^2+b^2+2ab > a^2 + b^2 -ab \Rightarrow (a+b)^2 > a^2 + b^2 -ab \Rightarrow a+b > \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 -ab}$

I was able to do this by squaring the original inequality I was supposed to prove, and then I worked backwards.

Comment: But can you take the square root without the inequality flipping?

Comment: of course, because we didn't multiply by a negative number :)

Comment: You have to check that $a^2+b^2-ab$ is positive, which is the case (cf my post). Otherwise you can't directly apply the square function.

Comment: Also we know that both sides are positive, so no problem with taking a square root.

Answer (score 2):

$3ab>0$

Hence, $2ab>-ab$

Hence, $a^2+2ab+b^2>a^2+b^2-ab$

Hence $a+b>\sqrt{a^2+b^2-ab}$ because $a^2+b^2-ab>a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2>0$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

...........................................................